# Sort out columns of multiple csv files at once in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, csv

really appreciate your help.

I have around 200 csv files with same header.
eg of headers are `x , y, z, time, id, type`

I would like to sort out `time` colums of all csv files and save them again.

This is so far I have tried. But it doesn't work.

Could you please help me ??

Thank you

```
import csv
import operator
import glob
import pandas as pd

data = dict() # filename : lists

path="./*.csv"
files=glob.glob(path)

for filename in files:
    # process each file
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        # read file to a list of lists
        lists = [row for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')]
        # sort and save into a dict
        sorted_df = lists.sort_values(by=["time"], ascending=True)
        sorted_df.to_csv('%.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: If you want them sorted by time, why would you sort them by "id"?

Comment: So, this is not your real code?  Because this will create a file called `%i.csv` and overwrite it, over and over and over.

Comment: yes, not real one. I added sorted_df lines to save files.

Comment: So, what is your problem?

Comment: It wasn't working before. I solved it. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much knowledge about the `csv` module but you're using `pandas` and it supports reading csv files with `pd.read_csv`, why not utilize that..

```
for filename in files:
  df = pd.read_csv(filename)
  df.sort_values('time', inplace=True)
  df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

This would overwrite all the files with same data sorted by time.